# Monitor the progress of pyspark's `applyInPandas()`

Tags: python, pyspark, parallel-processing, databricks, hpc

In Databricks, we use the Python command

```
spark_df.groupBy("variable1").applyInPandas(python_function, schema=schema)
```

to run the `python_function` on subsets of the `spark_df`. The command works fine and the computation also scales to 100+ CPUs. However, it takes a couple of hours to finish, and it would be great to monitor the progress of the computation.

Is there a way to monitor the progress of the computation?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can monitor by using the [Spark Web UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/web-ui.html).

If you did not change any default values, the web UI should be running on port 4040 of the machine on which your driver is running.

Browse to that port, using a web browser, and you should be able to monitor your job/stage/task progress in real time!

Some examples:

- If your driver is running on your local laptop, simply browse to `localhost:4040` using a web browser
- If your driver is running on some pod in kubernetes, port-forward the driver's 4040 port to your local pc using `kubectl port-forward <driver-pod-name> 4040:4040` and browse to `localhost:4040` again.
- ...